# Esp32-WROOM-32D can't connect to my home wifi

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I am trying to get my esp32 to connect to my wifi, but it attempts forever without connecting. I don't think there is anything wrong with the code. I'm thinking the issue is something with my router.

```
#include<WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "mySSID";  
const char *password = "myPW";
        
void initWiFi() {
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print('.');
        delay(1000);
      }
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      initWiFi();
      Serial.print("RRSI: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    }
```

I have a netgear router that puts out a 2.4G and 5G network. I ran a WiFi scan sketch on my esp32 and it successfully saw my 2.4Ghz wifi and identified it was using WPA2. I checked my router log and saw it thought my esp32 connection attempts were DoS attacks so i disabled DoS protection, and added my esp32's mac address to the allow list. None of that worked. any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I checked my code vs your code. I can only see one difference.

```
// Debug information
#define DEBUG 1

#if DEBUG ==1
    #define debug(x) Serial.print(x)
    #define debugln(x) Serial.println(x)
#else
    #define debug(x) 
    #define debugln(x) 
#endif


#define vtDelay(x) vTaskDelay(x / portTICK_PERIOD_MS)

void initWiFi() {
  debug("Start initWiFi");
      // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  //WiFi.disconnect();
  vtDelay(1000);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  debugln("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  WiFiAttempts = 1;
  while (WiFiRet != WL_CONNECTED ) {
    WiFiRet = WiFi.status();
    debug("WiFi.status  = ");
    debug(WiFiRet);
    debug("   WiFiAttempts = ");
    debugln(WiFiAttempts++);
    vtDelay(1000);

    if (WiFiAttempts > 20) {
        debugln("Restarting the ESP32");
        ESP.restart();
    }

  }
  debugln(WiFi.localIP());
}
```

This works for me the only difference was the vtDelay for 1000 milliseconds. I am also using my 2.4G and have security set to 'WPA2-PSK'.

I hope this helps.